# Is there anymore documentation on the IDML HTMLItem specification and HTMLItem poster property?

Tags: base64, adobe-indesign, idml

I'm working with coding with the IDML documents and I'm looking for more information on the IDML HTMLItem. I have both the version 7 and version 8 of the IDML specification and have not found anymore information then a small mention in the "new elements" of version 8,

> The HtmlItem element has been added as a child element to the 
>   element,  element (see "Graphics" on page 91),
>    element,  element and  element. This
>   element is the embedded HTML item.

***Has anyone has found anymore detailed information this specific object or it's properties?*** Specifically there is a property called, "Poster" that looks like thumbnail data. Here is my example:

```
            <HtmlItem Self="udc" HtmlContent="This &lt;i&gt;is an&lt;/i&gt; &lt;b&gt;HTML snippet &lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;DUDE&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;." FixedDimensions="true" RelativeSubPath="This &lt;i&gt;is an&lt;/i&gt; &lt;b&gt;HTML snippet &lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt;DUDE&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/b&gt;." ParentInterfaceChangeCount="" TargetInterfaceChangeCount="" LastUpdatedInterfaceChangeCount="" OverriddenPageItemProps="" HorizontalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" VerticalLayoutConstraints="FlexibleDimension FixedDimension FlexibleDimension" LocalDisplaySetting="Default" AppliedObjectStyle="n" Visible="true" Name="$ID/" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 -50 -50">
                <Properties>
                    <Poster><![CDATA[iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAmCAYAAACBFtRsAAAFtklEQVR42u1cPY7yP...==]]></Poster>
                    <PathBoundingBox Left="0" Top="0" Right="200" Bottom="38" />
                    <GraphicBounds Left="0" Top="0" Right="200" Bottom="38" />
                </Properties>
                <TextWrapPreference Inverse="false" ApplyToMasterPageOnly="false" TextWrapSide="BothSides" TextWrapMode="None">
                    <Properties>
                        <TextWrapOffset Top="0" Left="0" Bottom="0" Right="0" />
                    </Properties>
                </TextWrapPreference>
            </HtmlItem>
```

I stripped out the full value of the Poster tag but I've pasted it into a bin at http://pastebin.com/s5ZfFfyW. ***Is this base64 encoded image data?***

InDesign Documentation - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html#idml

Comment: That looks like [Base-64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) data. Decompressing it with [a random Base64 decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp), I got a PNG file, recognizable by its header, containing an image that says "This is an HTML snippet DUDE". (You hopefully know where that came from.)

Comment: OK. Thanks! I tried that site earlier and it was confusing but I tried again and selected decode and changed the output file name from "base64.bin" to "base64.png" and downloaded the file and it's showing an image of the content I created.

Comment: Knowing that, you may be able to find it now in the documentation.

Comment: Erm, no luck on searching for related topics based on the search terms, "base", "base64", "base 64" and "encoding".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no additional documentation at this time. And in testing it looks like the poster property contains Base-64 encoded data.